# Property 'hubConnection' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic' - ReactJS

Tags: jquery, reactjs, typescript, signalr

I using Signalr library with React but getting this error: `Property 'hubConnection' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'.` Is there any way to fix it?

```
declare var window : any;

import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
require('ms-signalr-client');

const connection = $.hubConnection("http://x.x.x.x/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps needed to make this work.

## Declaration

Before the use of `$.hubConnection` you need to state this:

```
declare var $: any;
```

## Libraries & Types

Install the official SignalR client, with jQuery, and types for them. The one you're using for SignalR, `ms-signalr-client`, is unofficial and now [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms-signalr-client).

```
yarn add signalr
yarn add jquery
```

Add types:

```
yarn add --dev @types/jquery 
yarn add --dev @types/signalr
```

## Scripts Recognition

You need to tell Angular about the scripts, via the `angular.json` file.

```
"architect": {
   "build": {
      "options": [{
         "scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "../node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.min.js"
         ],
```